# Setting messageId in Azure Function Service Bus output bindings

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Using Azure Functions v3 and the Node.js API, is there a way to set the `messageId` property value for Service Bus output bindings?

At present I am binding messages using the following approach (pulled from [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript#example)).

```js
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var message = 'Service Bus queue message created at ' + timeStamp;
    context.log(message);   
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue = message;
};
```

This works for setting the body of the message, but doesn't allow for configuring other properties.

Compare this to the `@azure/service-bus` approach and its `ServiceBusSender.sendMessages` method ([described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/service-bus/servicebussender?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-service-bus-servicebussender-sendmessages)). This method accepts an argument of type `ServiceBusMessage` which allows setting (among other things) a `messageId` property.

Can this be done using Functions Service Bus output bindings or is this a limitation of the API?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible yet to set `messageId` property in output bindings, this is the limitation of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, It is not possible yet to set  `messageId`  property in output bindings, this is the limitation of the API.

I tried to set the  `messageId`  property by following method and it worked for me. as shown below:

I created a service bus client and sent the message to queue.

**`Myfunction`:**

**`index.js`**

```js
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");

var connectionString = process.env.servicebusoutputbind_SERVICEBUS;
var queueName = process.env.queue;

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);

    var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

    var sender = serviceBusClient.createSender(queueName);

    var message_body= 'Service Bus queue message created at ' + timeStamp;
    var message_id = timeStamp;

    var message = {
    body: message_body,
    messageId: message_id,
    };
    sender.sendMessages(message).then((_) => {
    console.log("Message sent with messageId: " + message.messageId);
    sender.close();
    serviceBusClient.close();
    });
};
```

**`pacakage.json`:**

```json
{
  "name": "javascript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/service-bus": "^7.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**`function.json`:**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`Environment variables - in Azure`:**

[image]

#**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]